# MS Access Link to an Excel Document on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, hyperlink

Hi I am trying to link an excel document that is on sharepoint an "Http://..."  but every time I try to link any file it gives me a list. I don't want to link the list I want to be able to pull the data from the actual excel document aand not a list of the file that are on sharepoint. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is right but everything that I have found indicates that access will see those things on sharepoint as only "blank blocks" and will not pull the data from the actual files I may be wrong as the article and forums that I found are dated from 2013 and 2012 couldn't find anything else with a newer date. Thanks : ). What I did find was that I can use a macro to download the files very quickly and locate them someone in my shared drive and update them every month or so that access is update and link the file to access via excel files.